# In laravel 8 uploading file causing 419 | Page Expired

Tags: laravel

I have a form with CSRF field. I am uploading 9MB excel file and it is causing me 419 Page expired.

I have set the php.ini and .htaccess file with max variables but no luck.

This is my .htaccess file with variables.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    ###########
    php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2500M
php_value max_execution_time=600000
php_value max_input_time 6000000
php_value memory_limit 2500M
    
</IfModule>
```

The php.ini also have same values.
The Path of this .htaccess is public folder.

I have also added posts in verfiyCsrfToken middleware for testing.

```
protected $except = [
        //
        'posts/*'
    ];
```

But still i am facing issue.

If you upload file with small size it is working perfect.

Comment: `419` error comes with CSRF mismatch mostly. In your case page may be getting too late in submitting the request. Search file upload PHP settings

Answer (score 0):

Open up your php.ini file and change these keys

```
post_max_size = 8M to post_max_size = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 2M to upload_max_filesize = 256M
```

Make sure you restart your Apache after changing this. Thanks